# Position fixed not working on mobile Chrome when scrolling up with virtual keyboard open

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, css-position

I have a chatbot app made with React. My issue is my input field, which should stay fixed at the bottom at all times. At first it stays fixed above the virtual keyboard as intended, but then disappears under the virtual keyboard if I scroll up about halfway through. This issue only occurs on mobile Chrome, not on Safari or Samsung browser.

This is how my fixed input field looks like:

JSX of input field:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.input-field}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <textarea value={inputValue} placeholder='Enter your message' onKeyDown={enterKeyHandler} onChange={messageHandler} aria-label='enter your message'></textarea>
        <IconButton title="Send" type="submit" aria-label='send'><img src='img/send-button.png' className={styles.button-icon} alt="send"/></IconButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
```

CSS:

```
.input-field {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

This is how its parent container looks like:

JSX:

```
  return (
    <div className={isOpen ? `${styles.chat-container} ${styles.chat-open}` : `${styles.chat-container} ${styles.chat-closed}`}>
        <ChatHeader/>     
        <div className={styles.chat-inner}>
         ...
        </div>       
      <ChatInput/> <!-- the affected input -->
    </div>
  )
```

```
.chat-container {
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
.chat-open {
   display: flex;
}

.chat-closed {
   display: none;
}
```

I tried replacing `position: fixed` with `position: absolute` and `position: sticky` but the same thing happens. I've also tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1"/>` in my `index.html` meta tag as I've seen suggested but it did nothing. For what it's worth it seems like the issue occurs when I scroll up and the header (which also has `position: fixed` and also suffers from same behavior) gets into the viewport. Then again, the issue doesn't occur on other browsers or when the virtual keyboard is closed so I'm a bit lost here. Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show HTML code, and full CSS style of the problematic element?

Comment: I edited my question to include JSX and CSS for both the input and its parent element

Comment: When asking such questions, you need to only supply the generated HTML and CSS. Anything else is just noise and gets in the way

Comment: I have the same issue with `position: sticky`, works everywhere but on chrome